# Relation *tablename* does not exist

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Recently I'm getting an error message that I don't know how to deal with. It's very vague.

The PostgreSQL statement I use is:

```
    $result = pg_query($ruledbconnection, "INSERT INTO INPUT(num, pkts, bytes ,
    target,prot, opt, \"in\", out, source, destination, id) 
    VALUES('$num','$bytes','$pkts','$target', '$opt', '$protocol', '$in', '$out',
   '$source', '$destination', '$id')");
```

All seems fine, right? However, when I execute this query with variables:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'INPUT'" LINE 1: INSERT INTO 'INPUT'(num, pkts, bytes ,
target, prot, opt, "i... ^
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and it might be due escaping in PHP, or maybe something else?

The table that I want to manipulate is called INPUT in my database..

Comment: you really need a space after the table name `INPUT (num,`

Comment: Unfortunately still getting almost the same error!

`ERROR: relation "input" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO INPUT (num, pkts, bytes , target, prot, opt, "in... ^`

Comment: try to quote the table identifier

Comment: Another solution would be to rename your `INPUT` table into something more descriptive.  As it is, `INPUT` is only slightly more descriptive than `DATA` as a name.

Comment: Your SQL does not match the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL you showed doesn't match the error. The SQL doesn't have quotes around the table name, the error does.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'INPUT'" LINE 1: INSERT INTO 'INPUT'(num, pkts, bytes ,
```

So. Single quotes (apostrophes, `'`) are for SQL *values*, not *identifiers*. Identifiers are quoted with double quotes (`"`). So you'd write:

```
INSERT INTO "INPUT" (...) VALUES (...)
```

Note that quoting the table name will *preserve case*.  So if you double quote it here, you must double quote it everywhere you refer to it from. You will save your sanity if you instead just use lower case:

```
INSERT INTO input (...) VALUES (...)
```

and even better, a descriptive table name:

```
INSERT INTO packets_received (...) VALUES (...)
```

---

Your syntax error is the least of your problems, though. Let me introduce you to a classic:

[image: SQL Injection - XKCD]

Your query follows the pattern:

```
pg_query($conn, 'INSERT INTO sometable (col) VALUES ($user_input)')
```

and thus, is a classic example of [an SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Read:

- [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)
- [PHP manual on SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by making sure that I escape the quotes around my table name.

```
"INSERT INTO INPUT (num, pkts, bytes , target, prot, opt, \"in\", out, source, destination, id)
```

Should be:

```
"INSERT INTO \"INPUT\" (num, pkts, bytes , target, prot, opt, \"in\", out, source, destination, id)
```

Comment: You have not escaped the name, you quoted it and then escaped the quotes.